# pairwise_cor in R with Grouped data

Tags: r, graph, igraph

I'm trying to get the correlations with word1 and word2 but with a extra column called university name.

`

```
 palabras_correlacion <- Abstract_universities %>%
       
      group_by(palabra) %>%
      filter(n() >= 8) %>%
      arrange(Universidad) %>% 
         pairwise_cor(palabra,
                   seccion,
                   sort = TRUE)
```

`
But Only I get the words with the correlations.

[Display one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pj22E.png)

Before to aplied the pairwise function I had this table "Abstract_universities".

```
# A tibble: 15,854 × 8
   Universi…¹ Titul…² Titul…³ Titul…⁴ Titul…⁵ palab…⁶ seccion palabra
   <chr>      <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>     <int> <chr>  
 1 Rosario    Acerca… https:… D´Ange… 2015-0… Incapa…       1 objeti…
 2 Rosario    Acerca… https:… D´Ange… 2015-0… Incapa…       1 indagar
 3 Rosario    Acerca… https:… D´Ange… 2015-0… Incapa…       1 fundam…
 4 Rosario    Acerca… https:… D´Ange… 2015-0… Incapa…       1 jurídi…
 5 Rosario    Acerca… https:… D´Ange… 2015-0… Incapa…       1 psicol…
 6 Rosario    Acerca… https:… D´Ange… 2015-0… Incapa…       1 desarr…
 7 Rosario    Acerca… https:… D´Ange… 2015-0… Incapa…       1 susten…
 8 Rosario    Acerca… https:… D´Ange… 2015-0… Incapa…       1 estatu…
 9 Rosario    Acerca… https:… D´Ange… 2015-0… Incapa…       1 incapa…
10 Rosario    Acerca… https:… D´Ange… 2015-0… Incapa…       1 psíqui…
```

If I use pairwise_count works!

```
pares_palabras <- Abstract_universities %>%
      group_by(Universidad) %>% 
      pairwise_count(palabra,
                     seccion,
 sort = T)
```

[Display 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2HB5.png)

I want to do the same with pairwise_cor

Sorry for my english i'm not a native english speaker.

I want to do four column: item1,item2, correlation and University. With this, I want to do a ggraph that show the co occurency words and from what university are them.

Comment: please provide your dataset `Abstract_universities` , see post here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I suggest adding your data set so that your question will be reproducible. To do it, run `dput(Abstract_universities)` and copy the output which starts with `structure()`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your problem and your data, try this

```
Abstract_universities %>%
  nest(.by = Universidad) %>% 
  mutate(
    data = map(
      data, 
      ~ pairwise_cor(., palabra, seccion, sort = TRUE)
    )
  ) %>% 
  unnest(data)
```

You can check if the above gives the desired output, by looking at one university and comparing it with the above result for the same university

```
test_1 <- Abstract_universities %>%
  filter(Universidad == "Rosario") %>%
  pairwise_cor(palabra, seccion, sort = TRUE) 

test_2 <- Abstract_universities %>%
  nest(.by = Universidad) %>% 
  mutate(
    data = map(
      data, 
      ~ pairwise_cor(., palabra, seccion, sort = TRUE)
    )
  ) %>% 
  unnest(data)

identical(
  test_1,
  # there's one more column - drop it to do the identical test
  test_2 %>% filter(Universidad == "Rosario") %>% select(-Universidad) 
)
```

I think `group_by` is not supported for what you are looking for, see [this](https://github.com/juliasilge/widyr/issues/17).

Another approach would be to loop by university, save your results in a list and then `bind_rows` the list.

Hope this helps.